# Using sceneform dependency in android studio module

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to use sceneform dependencies in android studio module. But it says an error:

> Sceneform may only be applied to Android projects

Though, using the same dependencies in app module's gradle file works well.

My app module's build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            /*
             * Sceneform is available for the following ABIs: arm64-v8a, armv7a,
             * x86_64 and x86. This sample app enables arm64-v8a to run on
             * devices and x86 to run on the emulator. Your application should
             * list the ABIs most appropriate to minimize APK size (arm64-v8a recommended).
             */
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'

sceneform.asset('models/Tables/table1.fbx',
        'default',
        'models/Tables/table1.sfa',
        'src/main/res/raw/table1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to enter `sceneform:plugin` in your project gradle file?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.3.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In app build.gradle it must be

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.12.0'
}
```

In project build.gradle you must include Sceneform plugin

```
plugins {
id 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin' }
```

Also don't forget about the dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.12.0"
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:assets:1.17.1'}
```